# HSM returns a 67 byte ECDSA-secp256k1 public key, what does this mean?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, hsm

I generate a key on the HSM through the Graphene library, except when I try to get the public key raw value by getting its 'pointEC' attribute (equivalent to `CKA_EC_POINT`), I get a 134 character string:

`044104c9d5b656518b5b7e0d747b86328c37a0d507de9b3863a43e77b559ab60c0f9b15985f83a8c20588164c0634f98eb4a4cf8ce70020e94ae21a247904fac8b1010`

Now, I understand for this standard there's an X and Y integer, but I read that some math is required to make them valid for generating an Ethereum address. I also understand that the '04' means that it is an *uncompressed* public key, but I do not know why the '4104' keeps popping up or what it means. Are these just different ways of representing the same data? Could I just take the last 128 characters and hash it for a valid Ethereum address?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: The Ethereum address is just the Keccak hash of the last 20 bytes of the public key.  So - last 40 characters.  You'll need to make sure the public key is formatted similarly though, since you're getting it from some HSM and it's a raw value (byte order, x/y coordinate order in point, padding above 32 bits possible, etc).

Comment: Is there a way to test if it'd be valid without making an actual transaction? I would just hash the last 128 characters, correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is a *BER/DER encoded uncompressed point*. The first byte valued `04` is *not* the uncompressed point indicator. That's the 3rd byte. The first byte valued `04` encodes the tag byte for an ASN.1 OCTET STRING (also known as a byte array to most developers). You can view the structure [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#BEEEydW2VlGLW34NdHuGMow3oNUH3ps4Y6Q-d7VZq2DA-bFZhfg6jCBYgWTAY0-Y60pM-M5wAg6UriGiR5BPrIsQEA).

The byte with hex value `41` is the size of the bytes that comes after: 1 byte for the `04` uncompressed point indicator, 32 bytes for the *statically sized* X-coordinate and 32 bytes for the Y-coordinate.

So yes, you can take the last 64 bytes and split it in two if you need the X- and Y-coordinate. The 128 characters are just the hexadecimal representation of those bytes - but you should just worry about the bytes.

Of course, what you *should* do is to parse the ASN.1, determine and validate the length, take the uncompressed point, decode it *and check that it is on the curve* to validate your input. An EC key is valid if it includes the correct parameters. For Ethereum / BitCoin the curve is however implicitly known (secp256k1).

Comment: So to take the address, do I or do I NOT hash the public key with the 04? With the 0x?

Comment: No, what you hash is the bytes of the public key. So that's without either `04` byte and length encoding. I.e. it's just the last 64 bytes. After a bit of a search I found this info [here](https://etherworld.co/2017/11/17/understanding-the-concept-of-private-key-public-key-and-address-in-ethereum-blockchain/). Then you take the rightmost 20 bytes of the resulting hash hash. Do NOT hash the hexadecimal encoding or the `0x` bytes. Again, that's just the human readable representation of the key.